# Rails action after pressing button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `buy` method in my `item` controller and I tried to print user email who have pressed `buy` button, but I don't know how to do it. Is there a way to do it without creating Buy model, where I can connect user with my models?

my buy method:

```
def buy
    item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
    item.ammount -= 1
    item.save
    flash[:success] = "You bought item"
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't be afraid to make another model. If you want to have persistent access to this information, you'll have to put it in a table.

Comment: Ok, I will do another model then.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some better code, using [`decrement!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/decrement!):

```
def buy
    item = current_user.items.find params[:id]
    item.decrement! :amount
    redirect_to :back, success: "Item purchased"
end
```

If you want your own user to buy one of their items, you would not need a separate model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | user_id | amount | purchased | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```
def buy
   @item = current_user.items.find params[:id]
   @item.decrement! :amount
   @item.increment! :purchased
end
```

Quite why you'd want to do this, I don't know.

---

However, if you wanted to make it so that a user can buy another user's items, you'll be able to use a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) model as follows:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
   has_many :purchases
   has_many :purchased_items, through: :purchases, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: :item_id
end

#app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   bleongs_to :user

   after_create :decrease

   private

   def decrease
       item.decrement!
   end
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :purchases
   has_many :purchasers, through: :purchases, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :items do
   resource :purchase, only: [:create]
end

#app/controllers/purchase_controller.rb
class PurchaseController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @item = Item.find params[:item_id]
      @purchase = current_user.purchases.create @item
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to "buy" items from other users